# Get top-most executing TestSuite in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I need to know the suite class that included the currently running JUnit test. For example, if you have

```
@SuiteClasses({SubSuite.class})
class ParentSuite { }

@SuiteClasses({TestCase.class})
class SubSuite { }

class TestCase {
    @Test
    public void testMethod() { }
}
```

and execute `ParentSuite` with JUnit, then I want to get a reference to `ParentSuite.class`. Is this possible?

There is the `TestWatcher` rule that gets you an instance of `Description`, which is kind of in the right direction, but that does not include the suite class.

I know this is probably not the best way to write unit tests. My original problem is to run a validation on all classes that are in the project under test, but not those of the dependencies. The `TestCase` will be in a dependency and included by test suites in other projects. The only solution I could think of is filter those classes with the same source location as that of the top-most-suite. To make that more clear:

```
BaseLibrary
    * contains TestCase and TestSuite
    * has classes that should not be validated
ConsumerProject
    * has a test-scoped and test-classified dependency to BaseLibrary
    * contains ParentSuite
    * has classes that should be validated
```

Comment: Why you need to do this is still unclear to me. What build system (if any) are you using? It should be possible to isolate tests to their respective projects. Why does your suite include tests from multiple projects?

Comment: I use maven. The suite contains the normal unit tests of ConsumerProject and the mentioned TestCase that should validate all tests of ConsumerProject. There are multiple projects, so I want to have the validating test case in the BaseLibrary.  But our should only check the consumer test cases, not its own, when called from the consumer's suite. It is not a test in the strict sense of the word, more a static analysis, but it is handy to implement it as a JUnit test.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use JUnit @Category https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories

Here's a blog on how to make Categories https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/04/25/grouping-tests-using-junit-categories-0

This way you can make Categories for each of your projects.

```
public interface ConsumerProject {}
```

Then you can use the @Category annotation to mark test classes (or even test methods) as being in particular categories:

```
@Category(ConsumerProject.class)
public class TestCase { ... }
```

Then your suites can be set up to run all the tests for particular categories

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(ConsumerProject.class)
@SuiteClasses( { ....}) 
public class ConsumerProjectSuite { }
```

You can even have the same test get marked with multiple categories

```
@Category({ConsumerProject.class, OtherProject.class})
public class CommonTests {  }
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it does not work for me. The whole point of the test is to detect simple mistakes, and this just adds one to the list of things so can forget writing the tests.